# How to ensure a generic parameter is not Nullable?

Tags: c#, generics, nullable

I am trying to make a class `GameOption` that will hold three (really four) values:

- Name of Option as string
- An option as T
- A default value as Nullable< T >

This how looks my class:

```
public class GameOption<T> {
    private T v;
    private string n;
    private T? def;
    public string Name { get => this.n; }
    public T Value { get => this.v; }
    public GameOption(T o, string name, T? def) {
        this.n = name;
        this.v = o;
    }
    public void ChangeValue(T o) {
        this.v = o;
    }
}
```

But there is a problem. T cannot be Nullable as VS says:

> The type T must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method Nullable

How do I make sure that T is not Nullable?

Is there something like `class X<@NotNull T>` or what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To ensure the type `T` is not nullable constrain it to a `struct`:

```
public class GameOption<T> where T : struct { }
```

[Generic Constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters)

Answer (score 7):

Nowadays :

```
public class GameOption<T> where T : notnull { }
```